# Adding metadata link to layer.resource in GeoServer with Python gsconfig?

Tags: python, geoserver, metadata, geoserver-rest-api, gsconfig

I'm parsing layers from a catalog and I would like to edit metadata links directly from the code.

Until now, I tried:

```
cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/", XX, YYY)
layers = cat.get_layers()
for layer in layers:
    lyr = cat.get_layer("layer_name")
    lyr.resource.metadata_links.append(('text/html', 'other', 'metadata.html'))
    cat.save(lyr)
```

---- EDIT -----
Found out the answer, see below.

Answer (score 2):

I found out by myself investigating class and methods structure: to do it we've to get the resource. [Doc here](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig/blob/master/doc/model.rst#working-with-resources).

```
cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/", XX, YYY)
layers = cat.get_layers()
for layer in layers:
    rsc = cat.get_resource("layer_name",
                           store=layer.resource._store.name)
    rsc.metadata_links= [('text/html', 'other', 'metadata.html'),]
    cat.save(rsc)
```